# Using getmapasync() function instead of getmap() function in Android to plot GeoJSON file?

Tags: geojson, google-maps, android, geospatial-pdf

This is the code that I have used to plot GeoJSON file in Google Maps in Android:

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    GeoJsonLayer cul_els = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), R.raw.cultural_elements,
            getApplicationContext());
    cul_els.addLayerToMap();
```

I know since `getMap()` has been deprecated, we need to use `getMapAsync()` but how? When I replace the line

```
GeoJsonLayer cul_els = new GeoJsonLayer (getMap(),R.raw.cultural_elements,getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

GeoJsonLayer cul_els = new GeoJsonLayer(mapFragment.getMapAsync(this), R.raw.cultural_elements,getApplicationContext());
```

I get an error like this:

```
Unhandled exceptions: java.io.IOException, org.json.JSONException
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Answers to similar question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync

Answer (score -2):

You could try to simply wrap those expression in a `try-catch` block:

```
try{
 GeoJsonLayer cul_els = new GeoJsonLayer(map, R.raw.cultural_elements, getApplicationContext());
} catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: when i used getMap(), it says cannot resolve method getMap().

Comment: @user2711295 I edited the answer.

Comment: Now it says GeoJsonLayer() in GeoJson cannot be applied to map.

Comment: Then I suggest you to read some docs and other resources to get more familiar with the libraries. My solution was about the error you posted, not the general correctness of the code.

Comment: BTW you probably just need to initialize the map correctly and then pass the map object into this function, replacing the `getMapAsync()` function.

Comment: Thanks you are right. My initialization with the map was wrong. I created a getMap() function to return  the map and it worked.